# Having some random shapes while creating a custom text input layout in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I Have a custom TextInputLayout which i'm using inside my layout but for some reason i'm getting some shapes which i don't know what do they come from, i have posted my code below and thank you for any help in advance .

- Custom CenteredHintTextInputEditText

```
 class CenteredHintTextInputEditText @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : TextInputEditText(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    //region LifeCycle
    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        textInputEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
            updateHintPosition(hasFocus, !textInputEditText.text.isNullOrEmpty())
            val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            if (hasFocus)
                imm.showSoftInput(view, SHOW_IMPLICIT)
        }
        textInputEditText.addTextChangedListener {
            updateHintPosition(true, !textInputEditText.text.isNullOrEmpty())
        }
        textInputEditText.viewTreeObserver
                .addOnPreDrawListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
                    override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                        if ((textInputLayout?.height ?: 0) > 0) {
                            textInputLayout?.viewTreeObserver?.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                            updateHintPosition(
                                    textInputEditText.hasFocus(),
                                    !textInputEditText.text.isNullOrEmpty()
                            )
                            return false
                        }
                        return true
                    }
                })
    }
    //endregion

    //region Center hint
    private var paddingBottomBackup: Int? = null
    private var passwordToggleButtonPaddingBottomBackup: Float? = null
    private val textInputEditText: TextInputEditText
        get() {
            return this
        }
    private val textInputLayout: TextInputLayout?
        get() {
            return if (parent is TextInputLayout) {
                (parent as? TextInputLayout)
            } else {
                (parent?.parent as? TextInputLayout)
            }
        }
    private val passwordToggleButton: View?
        get() {
            return (parent as? View)?.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.password_toggle)
        }

    private fun updateHintPosition(hasFocus: Boolean, hasText: Boolean) {
        if (paddingBottomBackup == null)
            paddingBottomBackup = paddingBottom

        val inputLayoutSpace = if ((hasFocus || hasText).not()) getTextInputLayoutTopSpace() else 0

//        textInputEditText.setPadding(
//                paddingLeft,
//                paddingTop,
//                paddingRight,
//                inputLayoutSpace
//        )

        val button = passwordToggleButton
        button?.let {
            if (passwordToggleButtonPaddingBottomBackup == null) {
                passwordToggleButtonPaddingBottomBackup = it.translationY
            }

            it.translationY = if (hasFocus || hasText) {
                -getTextInputLayoutTopSpace().toFloat() * 0.50f
            } else {
                passwordToggleButtonPaddingBottomBackup ?: 0f
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getTextInputLayoutTopSpace(): Int {
        var currentView: View = textInputEditText
        var space = 0
        do {
            space += currentView.top
            currentView = currentView.parent as View
        } while (currentView !is TextInputLayout)
        return (space * 1.2).toInt()
    }
    //endregion
}
```

- Xml Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:context="com.borusan.mannesmann.pipeline.scene.main.MainActivity">

   <data>

       <variable
           name="viewModel"
           type="com.borusan.mannesmann.pipeline.scene.login.login.LoginViewModel" />

       <variable
           name="directions"
           type="com.borusan.mannesmann.pipeline.scene.login.login.LoginDirections" />

       <variable
           name="callbacks"
           type="com.borusan.mannesmann.pipeline.scene.login.login.LoginCallbacks" />

   </data>

   <com.borusan.mannesmann.pipeline.internal.view.RootFrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:progressVisibility="@{viewModel.isProgressVisible}"
       app:touchableInProgress="true">
       
       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
           android:id="@+id/scroll_view_login"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

           <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:fillViewport="true">

               <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                   android:id="@+id/image_view_logo"
                   style="@style/TextField.Description.Grey"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_login_desc"
                   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"
                   android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_login_desc"
                   android:gravity="center"
                   android:maxLines="2"
                   android:singleLine="false"
                   android:text="@string/label_login_if_registered"
                   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

               <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                   android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_name"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/height_form_input"
                   android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_large"
                   android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_large"
                   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"
                   android:padding="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
                   android:theme="@style/TextInputLayout"
                   app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintText"
                   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view_logo"
                   app:isInputValid="@{ viewModel.usernameValid }">

                   <com.borusan.mannesmann.pipeline.internal.view.CenteredHintTextInputEditText
                       android:id="@+id/edit_text_name"
                       style="@style/InputFieldText.SingleLine.Text"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:hint="@string/login_hint_username"
                       android:text="@={ viewModel.username }"
                       tools:text="Ad" />

               </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

               <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                   android:id="@+id/text_input_layout_password"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/height_form_input"
                   android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_large"
                   android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_large"
                   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small"
                   android:padding="@dimen/margin_extra_small"
                   android:theme="@style/TextInputLayout"
                   app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintText"
                   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_input_layout_name"
                   app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                   app:passwordToggleTint="@color/black"
                   app:isInputValid="@{ viewModel.passwordValid }">

                   <com.borusan.mannesmann.pipeline.internal.view.CenteredHintTextInputEditText
                       android:id="@+id/edit_text_password"
                       style="@style/InputFieldText.SingleLine.Password"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       android:hint="@string/login_hint_password"
                       android:text="@={ viewModel.password }"
                       tools:text="123456" />

               </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

               <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                   android:id="@+id/label_forgot_password"
                   style="@style/TextField.HyperLink"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_large"
                   android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_password_gray"
                   android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_small"
                   android:text="@string/label_forgot_password"
                   android:onClick="@{() -> callbacks.navigate(directions.toForgotPassword)}"
                   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_input_layout_password" />

               <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                   android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                   android:layout_width="0dp"
                   app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="@dimen/button_min_width_percent"
                   android:layout_height="@dimen/height_login_button"
                   android:layout_gravity="end"
                   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top_login_button"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_xxl"
                   android:enabled="@{viewModel.loginButtonStatus}"
                   android:onClick="@{ () -> callbacks.login() }"
                   android:text="@string/login_sign_in"
                   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label_forgot_password"/>


           </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

       </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

           <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
               android:id="@+id/label_continue_without_login"
               style="@style/TextField.HyperLink"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_xxl"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:onClick="@{() -> callbacks.navigate(directions.toHome)}"
               android:text="@string/label_continue_without_login"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scroll_view_login"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

   </com.borusan.mannesmann.pipeline.internal.view.RootFrameLayout>

</layout>
```

- Xml style used for theme

```
<style name="TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
       <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/ErrorText</item>
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_grey</item>
       <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/dark_grey</item>
       <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/transparent</item>
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_text_input</item>
   </style>
```

- Image that shows the issue i'm talking about

[image]